# Set static variable if condition equals true with batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to give the user an option to either use a default directory, or use their own directory as the variable `%1`. Here is what I have:

```
if ("%1"=="default") {set %1=C:\TestExecution\test}
set source=%1
IF NOT EXIST "%source%" goto error3

goto end
:error3
echo.
echo Error: Invalid Path
echo %source%
goto end
:end
```

When trying to test it out using cmd, here is the results:

```
c:\TestExecution>test.bat default 10.42.232.245

Error: Invalid Path
default
```

If anyone knows the right syntax for this and could help a person new to this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if "%~1"=="default" (set "source=C:\TestExecution\test") else set "source=%~1"
```

Comment: That worked, I just had forgot to remove the `set source=%1` 3 lines down. Thanks for the help :D